# I'm getting different HTML documents in JSoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to fetch a html document by URL. When I open this Url by chrome and when I display page's source, I see that the document here is different from the document that I fetch in my app. 
So I can't extract required elements. Have you ever seen the problem like that?

Comment: could be that client side scripting manipulates the DOM

Comment: Shouldn`t I trust the viewed page source ? I need to extract the some tags from this page but i can't do because of difference

Comment: page source you view is the one after it got manipulated on client side,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be because your JSOUP request has a different `User Agent` from the one your browser has. Change it by doing something like this:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("myURL")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
        .get();
```

You can find the exect `USER AGENT` string by launching your browser's developer tools (f12) and checking the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Document document;
String url = "www.google.com";
Response response;

try {

    response = Jsoup
        .connect(url)
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .userAgent(
         "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0.1")
        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
        .timeout(12000)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .execute();

    document = response.parse();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code is doing. And, next time, try to format it in a readable way.

Comment: it is a basic concept of connecting from jsoup to certain URL that's it.

Comment: by the way, by looking at above code it is trying to access to google.